# Unable to use wifienterpriseconfig in android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

I'm trying to use the `WifiEnterpriseConfig` and Eclipse isn't recognizing it, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, or not doing at all.

I have included:

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiEnterpriseConfig;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
The import android.net.wifi.WifiEnterpriseConfig cannot be resolved
```

I've updated my SDK to include the API 18, and I've updated Eclipse. Is there something else I'm missing?

I've clean/build several times, and also closed and reloaded Eclipse several times and nothing is working. I've also gone into Android Tools > Add Support Library.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on  your project => `Properties` => `Java Build Path` =>
  `Order and Export tab` => check `Android Private Libraries` and
  select OK
- Clean Project

**NOTE:**  If you are using any Android Library projects that are using the support library, make sure you go to the properties of that project and do the same thing.